# Expected type specifier before Polynomial error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am getting the following error :

```
 error: expected type-specifier before ‘Polynomial’
 Polynomial *Polynomial = new Polynomial();
```

This is happening in the main method on this statement - 
Polynomial *Polynomial = new Polynomial();
I have defined the polynomial class like -

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
class Polynomial
{
    LinkedList<int> *linkedList;

public:
    Polynomial()
    {
        linkedList = new LinkedList<int>();
    }
 

    Polynomial *add(Polynomial polynomialOne, Polynomial polynomialTwo)
    {
        Polynomial *newPolynomial = new Polynomial();
        
        return newPolynomial;
    }
    void display()
    {
        
    }
};
```

LinkedList.h is declared like :

```
#include "Node.h"
template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
```

and Node.h like

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
class Node
{
public:
    T coefficient;
    T exponent;
    Node *next;
};
```

Comment: I don't see the line `Polynomial *Polynomial = new Polynomial();` used in your code. But you probably need `Polynomial *polynomial = new Polynomial();`. Note the small `p` in the variable name. Or even `Polynomial *poly = new Polynomial();`.

Comment: Oh yes That worked. I am moving from Java and C++ is giving me headache. I find quite some differences and I miss those often. But the errors are also not very descriptive. I am  I couldn't guess from the error if it was about that. Probably I need to change my naming convention either this small letters or put an underscore in from to avoid such errors in the future

Comment: What's the naming convention used in C++ to avoid such errors. I also noticed you cannot have variable names and method names same

Comment: @puneeta `Polynomial *newPolynomial = new Polynomial();` -- C++ is not Java.  Your code assumes that C++ is a reference-based language like Java.  It is value-based, not reference based.  Do not use Java as a model in writing C++ code.  First, there is no need to use `new` to create objects in C++, as you are making it easier to leak memory.  Unless `Polynomial` is non-copyable, you could have easily had `Polynomial add(whatever) { return Polynomial(); }` thus returning a `Polynomial` object by value.  Second, the parameters are passed by value, when you should be passing them by reference.

Comment: Also, `LinkedList<int> *linkedList;` could have simply been `LinkedList<int> linkedList;`, and thus no need for the call to `new LinkedList<int>` in the constructor.  Again, this looks like Java-type coding in a C++ program, and all that will do is to have buggy code, slow code, or code that will look totally weird to a C++ programmer.

Comment: ok. So `LinkedList<int> linkedList;` will automatically create an instance of LinkedList object ? That means it will invoke the constructor automatically ?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie When you say that c++ is "value based" you mean that you are encouraged to take advantage of stack based object allocation where the object is automatically destroyed when exiting its scope and it's preferable -when possible- to dynamic allocation on the heap, a burdensome operation that can cause memory fragmentation and leaks, and more work?

Comment: @MatG -- When you do this in C++: `A a1; A a2 = a1;` does not make a2 be a reference to a1.  An actual copy is done.  This is not the same with Java, where a1 and a2 refer to the same `A` object -- that is what I mean when saying C++ is *value-based*.  That is one of the major differences between C++ and Java, and the issues that makes Java programmers who attempt to write C++ code *without learning C++* that arises so many times.

Comment: @puneeta -- Yes, the instance is created automatically and the object is default constructed.  This is a basic fundamental of C++.

Comment: @puneeta, Sorry for the late reply. The compiler expects a type after your `new` operator, but you already have a variable of the same name as your type. So it's confused. I wouldn't recommend naming your variable same as your type (although I just learned this is possible: `Polynomial *Polynomial = new class Polynomial()`. I have not seen this used a lot in practice). Also, in general, as PaulMcKenzie mentioned, do not allocate memory on the heap unless it's really required (to live beyond the local scope, or too big to copy around, for example).